# может ли число быть двоичным?

Tags: c

Задача такова: пользователем вводится число N, и программа должна вывести ответ, может ли N быть двоичным(состоять только из 0 и 1). Например, если в числе есть какие-либо другие числа помимо 1 и 0, то ответ должен быть отрицательным. Сам программку написал, но когда сдал её на проверку, то при вводе, например, 1000010000000, выводит отрицательный ответ. Объясните, пожалуйста, в чем загвостка? Читать умею, буду благодарен и источнику с ответом.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("n = "); scanf_s("%d", &n);
    while (n)
    {
        int m = n % 10;
        if (m && m != 1)
        {
            printf("No");
            return 0;
        }
        n /= 10;
    }
    printf("Yes");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Число 1000010000000 слишком большое, чтобы уместиться в тип `int`. Используйте `long long`.

Comment: Ваше число, за счет переполнения, будет преобразовано в -717379968. Как верно отметили выше, используйте более объемный тип. Либо же строки, хотя с ними будет немного больше геморроя.

Comment: вводите как строку, а не как число. Потом двигаясь по символам если находите что-то отличное от 0 или 1 - ответ "нет", если дошли до конца строки - ответ - "да"

Comment: ого, интересная идея со строками, но как ее реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Через строки решение более практичное, на мой взгляд, так как не возникнет проблем с переполнением. Но со строками дополнительно необходимо проверять, нет ли символов, отличных от цифр

Пример:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* n = (char*) calloc(1000, sizeof(char));
    char* start = n;
    printf("n = "); scanf("%s", n);
    while (*n != '\0') {
        if(*n < '0' || *n >'9') {
            printf("Incorrect input");
            return -1;
        }
        n++;
    }
    n = start;
    while (*n != '\0') {
        if(*n < '0' || *n >'1') {
            printf("No");
            return -1;
        }
        n++;
    }
    printf("Yes");
    free(start);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: да не нужно ничего проверять) просто наличие 0 и 1 что угодно другое "No"

Comment: @DaniilLoban, по факту да, это красоты ради)

Comment: Если уж работать со строками, то проще всего использовать [strspn()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strspn) . Например -- `{char n[MAX_LINE]; n[0] = 0; scanf("%s", n); int l = strspn(n, "01"); printf("%s\n", (l && n[l] == 0) ? "Yes" : "No");}` (вот и весь код)